# Android - Compile error variable cannot be applied

Tags: java, android, enums

If have this enum type code and get this compile error.

[image]

I get that `Color.RED` is an int but Im not sure why I am getting the error?

```
 enum Direction {

    NORTH(Color.RED), WEST(Color.BLUE), EAST(Color.BLACK), SOUTH(
            Color.GREEN);

    Direction(Color c) {
        color = c;
    }

    private Color color;

    public static Direction fromName(String name) {
        for (Direction d : Direction.values()) {
            if (d.name().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return d;
            }
        }
        return NORTH;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
```

}
}

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Because you defined your constructor to take a Color as parameter, and you give it an int.

Comment: @ZouZou okay how could I fix this? and still be able to call it like this `Direction.fromName("south").getColor();`

Comment: Change your constructor to take an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public enum Direction {

NORTH(Color.RED), WEST(Color.BLUE), EAST(Color.BLACK), SOUTH(
        Color.GREEN);

Direction(int c) {
    color = c;
}
private int color;


public int get() {
    return color;
} 
}
```

and to get color in int format use :

```
Direction.SOUTH.get();
```

which will return int value for color "Green"

Comment: It returns this value "-16711936"? why not the hexdeciaml values?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#GREEN  ... that's the value of Green color!!! convert it to hexadecimal if you need!!!

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor you declare that the parameter has to be an instance of the class `Color`. `Color.RED` for instance however is returning an Integer.

So you would either

1. have to replace `Color.RED` and so on with objects of `Color`

OR

2. change your enum to store an `int`.

Comment: There are no Color objects, so go with option 2. All the methods of the class are static.

Comment: any chance you could post some short sample code of option 2

Comment: @ZouZou Oh right, mixed up the Color class from Android with the AWT one.